# Manipulate: how to hide manipulator

Tags: manipulate, core-language

Suppose one creates a simple Manipulate in a notebook, with a single numerical control and no changing of the default appearance.  Then there is a small + in the upper right, for accessing the bookmarks/autorun menu.  One of the options in this menu is "Hide Controls".  I would like to put the Manipulate in this state (i.e., hidden controls) when it is created, rather than interactively.  Possible?

Note that this is **not** the same as an `Invisible` control.  An invisible control cannot (afaict) be made visible interactively, whereas hidden controls appear if you click on the `Manipulate` display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update: New answer

Here is a not-any-less-obscure method, but it feels safer than the original one below:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"ShowControls" -> False}]
```

#### Original answer

The appearance of controls is controlled by a local hidden (or internal) variable `` Typeset`show$$ ``:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, Initialization :> (Typeset`show$$ = False)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: `` Typeset`show = False `` should also work, due to the way `Manipulate` remaps variable names.  Indeed it does, but it also creates the variable `` Typeset`show ``, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Pretty obscure.  But it works.